# Lenovo IdeaPad S145 touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

There are many similar questions in the forum but I couldn't find a solution.
I've purchased a new Lenovo Ideapad S145 and installed ubuntu 19.10.
And I can't get my touchpad to work.
I've tried adding multiple commands to grub's `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and of course ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted and it didn't seem to work.

When I'm pressing the `f6` key, it shows a touchpad icon with a small 'x'.

My Kernel version is 5.3.0-42-generic.

My `xinput` command result is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7):

I had this same issue. The problem is with the kernel. The kernel hasn't detected the touch pad. Firstly edit the kernel boot parameters. This is what i did to solve it -
EDIT: *It is recommended to take a backup using `cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak`*

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"`
3. Now save and exit.
4. Run `sudo update-grub`

*The next steps will be to patch the kernel*

5. Now run `git clone https://github.com/pavlepiramida/elan_i2c_dkms.git`
6. After that install make and dkms, so run `sudo apt install make dkms`
7. Now run `cd elan_i2c_dkms`
8. After that run `sudo dkms install .`
9. Finally, run `reboot`

**Now, once you reboot, the touch pad should be working perfectly fine!**
Glad I could help!

Comment: This works for me in Lenovo 14iiL05 for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Helped me with lenovo ideapad s145 on ubuntu mate 20.04

Comment: this does not work. Sorry.

Comment: @Mohamed I've seen many solutions for this problem and none worked, but this definitely did, so yea. Try again.

Comment: Tried with freshly installed Ubuntu 21.10 on Lenovo V15-IIL. Working, no need to patch the kernel. Thank you, Nikhil.

Answer (score 0):

The Lenovo IdeaPad S145 is not in the [list of Linux-compatible hardware](https://support.lenovo.com/au/en/solutions/pd031426) that Lenovo maintains.

It's likely to be the drivers, which may be too new to be available in the 19.10 kernel, or just not available. Have you tried `fwupd` to see if drivers are available?

There is good info on how to use it at the LVFS project [page](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/docs/users) as well as the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fwupd) .

Comment: There aren't *any* ideapads in that list.  I believe they just haven't tried for compatibility certification for the ideapad line.  Doesn't mean the machines won't work with Linux, just means they haven't targeted that.

Comment: Well I'm having a ton of problems with 20.04 so far on my IdeaPad 3 Gaming:

- Can't switch between nvidia and integrated AMD graphics after installing nvidia drivers
- Can't adjust screen brightness
- Touchpad not working