# Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Touchpad not working in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: grub2, kernel, mouse, touchpad, lenovo

So I've bought a Lenovo IdeaPad 5 and installed Ubuntu 21.04 on it. While a Mouse works just fine, the Touchpad does not. I've tried numerous methods I've found on YouTube and different forums. I edited a lot of things in grub and updated it, rebooted the laptop and also tried the [kernel method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220264/lenovo-ideapad-s145-touchpad-not-working/1266740#1266740) but unfortunately nothing works. I don't know if I should reinstall Ubuntu, try an older version or try a different Linux Distro. If anyone knows any other solution please let me know.

Comment: now I am installing 20.04 version

Answer (score -2):

I found out the solution! The Ubuntu version 21.4 doesn't support IdeaPad5 as of yet. I've installed older version 20.4 and the touchpad is working now.

Comment: Both versions now share the same kernel version. Hardware support in on the kernel. If by any chance you manage to install 20.04 with the original kernel branch and that one works where the new kernel doesn't that's a regression and should be reported as a bug.