# Lenovo IdeaPad S145 touchpad - not working on 22.04

Tags: kernel, touchpad, lenovo, 22.04

[Lenovo IdeaPad S145 touchpad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220264/lenovo-ideapad-s145-touchpad-not-working)

This link is working with kernel 5.13 but after update to Ubuntu 22.04, kernel got update to 5.15 and those options in Grub i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs made the kernel to not recognize nmve anymore:
[See image boot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuaTL.png)

So, how could we make the touchpad work again but not using those options in kernel?

Comment: The problem is with pci=nocrs, because with i8042.nopnp=1, the problem on booting doesn't happen. But, with only i8042.nopnp=1, touchpad is not working either.

Comment: It is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970056

Comment: Damn I am having the exact same problem and does't recognize the nvme with ubuntu 22.04 on my lenovo 15-IIL model with this fix. The kerner parameter fix used to work in ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I had the same problem with ubuntu 22.04 and the default 5.15 kernel, Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IIL05. The workaround for the touchpad (i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs) works only on mainline kernel 5.17.7 (warning, i had problems with zfs-dkms and mainline 5.17.7 kernel, but all ok with ext4 as / filesystem). Tried 5.16 and 5.14 from mainline too, don´t works...

Comment: Update: kernel v5.18 from mainline resolves this issue now :)